# What is a replacement for `write` and `format` in Perl 5?

Tags: perl, formatting, format

For simple output formatting I tend to use printf where I used write/format in the days of Perl 4. However sometimes it seems the simplest solution for variable numbers of output lines per data record. For example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($lorem, $aprille);

format =
@# ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< | ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$.,$aprille                  , $lorem
   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< | ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ~~
   $aprille                  , $lorem
                             |
.

while(<DATA>) {
  ($aprille, $lorem) = split(/\|/, $_, 2);
  write;
}

__DATA__
WHAN that Aprille with his shoures soote       |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
The droghte of Marche hath perced to the roote,|consectetur adipisicing elit,
And bathed every veyne in swich licour,        |sed do eiusmod tempor
Of which vertu engendred is the flour;         |incididunt ut labore et dolore
Whan Zephirus eek with his swete breeth        |magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
Inspired hath in every holt and heeth          |veniam, quis nostrud
The tendre croppes, and the yonge sonne        |exercitation exercitation
Hath in the Ram his halfe cours y-ronne,       |ullamco laboris nisi ut ali-
And smale fowles maken melodye,                |quip ex ea commodo conse-
That slepen al the night with open ye,         |quat. Duis aute irure dolor
So priketh hem nature in hir corages:          |in reprehenderit in volup-
Than longen folk to goon on pilgrimages,       |tate velit esse cillium dol-
And palmers for to seken straunge strondes,    |ore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
To ferne halwes, couthe in sondry londes;      |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
And specially, from every shires ende          |consectetur adipisicing elit,
Of Engelond, to Caunterbury they wende,        |sed do eiusmod tempor
The holy blisful martir for to seke,           |incididunt ut labore et dolore
That hem hath holpen, whan that they were seke.|magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
And now for something completely different. Nice plumage.|Norwegian blue.
```

Produces

```
   1 WHAN that Aprille with    | Lorem ipsum dolor
     his shoures soote         | sit amet,
                               |
   2 The droghte of Marche     | consectetur
     hath perced to the roote, | adipisicing elit,
                               |
   3 And bathed every veyne in | sed do eiusmod
     swich licour,             | tempor
  ...
  19 And now for something     | Norwegian blue.
     completely different.     |
     Nice plumage.             |
```

Note that record 19 occupies *three* lines.

What is an equivalent concise perl5ish way to do the above without using write and format?

Comment: write and format work in Perl 5. Why do you want/need to change it?

Comment: People often say there are problems with write and format. People often refer to it as deprecated. I've seen this often enough to believe it. I'm not sure what the problems are - which in itself is also a reason to consider alternatives.

Comment: `write/format` aren't deprecated, they're just esoteric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with formats is the reliance on global variables.  For other problems with formats, see pages 449 - 454 of [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735).

The modern solution would be [`Perl6::Form`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl6-Form/Form.pm).  This is a backport of what they are planning for Perl 6.

What follows is a rough translation of your format code to `Perl6::Form`.  I do not know `Perl6::Form` very well, so there may be ways to make it better or truer to your original example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Perl6::Form;

while(<DATA>) {
    my ($aprille, $lorem) = split(/\|/, $_, 2);
    print form(
        "{>} {[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[} | {[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[}",
        $.,  $aprille,                  $lorem,
        "                               |                     ",
    );
}

__DATA__
WHAN that Aprille with his shoures soote       |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
The droghte of Marche hath perced to the roote,|consectetur adipisicing elit,
And bathed every veyne in swich licour,        |sed do eiusmod tempor
Of which vertu engendred is the flour;         |incididunt ut labore et dolore
Whan Zephirus eek with his swete breeth        |magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
Inspired hath in every holt and heeth          |veniam, quis nostrud
The tendre croppes, and the yonge sonne        |exercitation exercitation
Hath in the Ram his halfe cours y-ronne,       |ullamco laboris nisi ut ali-
And smale fowles maken melodye,                |quip ex ea commodo conse-
That slepen al the night with open ye,         |quat. Duis aute irure dolor
So priketh hem nature in hir corages:          |in reprehenderit in volup-
Than longen folk to goon on pilgrimages,       |tate velit esse cillium dol-
And palmers for to seken straunge strondes,    |ore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
To ferne halwes, couthe in sondry londes;      |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
And specially, from every shires ende          |consectetur adipisicing elit,
Of Engelond, to Caunterbury they wende,        |sed do eiusmod tempor
The holy blisful martir for to seke,           |incididunt ut labore et dolore
That hem hath holpen, whan that they were seke.|magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
And now for something completely different. Nice plumage.|Norwegian blue.
```

Comment: That somewhat mischaracterizes the issue.  The variables that appear in the values lines of a format do not have to be globals. It’s more akin to the way that named functions in `%SIG` have to be in some package’s symbol table (`main::`’s by default). In the same way,  the per-handle `$~` and `$^` values reflect package names. You cannot get by with `$~ = *SOMETHING{FORMAT}`, although you can do `local $~ = "SOMETHING"`.

Comment: I *do* like the `Perl6::Form` approach; thanks for posting it. I’ve often written functions that take a `formline`ish first argument and used the rest of the positions to fill in the values line.

Comment: Owens: Thanks, the documentation for `Perl6::Form` is much more expansive and than `perldoc perlform` - amusing too. I think your example answers my question very well. The `Perl6::Form` usage looks to me like a more Perl5ish and more capable tool than the `write` and `format` inherited from Perl4.

Answer (score 4):

The main thing that perl5 added above perl4’s `format` and `write` is `formline`. There are a few other niceties, including `$^A`, numeric formats, and package scoping, but these are mainly nonessential fluff. The current set of formatting directives is only a bit greater than perl4’s:

```
@    start of regular field
^    start of special field
<    pad character for left justification
|    pad character for centering
>    pad character for right justification
#    pad character for a right justified numeric field
0    instead of first #: pad number with leading zeroes
.    decimal point within a numeric field
...  terminate a text field, show "..." as truncation evidence
@*   variable width field for a multi-line value
^*   variable width field for next line of a multi-line value
~    suppress line with all fields empty
~~   repeat line until all fields are exhausted
```

Other little-known enhancements include support for LC_NUMERIC local, being able to use a `{}`-delimited block to aid in alignment, and using a `\r` to force a true line-break.

I still use `format`s from time to time.  Here is a bit from a program I wrote only a couple of weeks ago.

```
sub init_screen() {
    our %Opt;
    my  $cols;

    if ($Opt{width}) {
         $cols  = $Opt{width};
    } 
    elsif (am_unixy()) {
        ($cols) = `stty size 2>&1` =~ /^\d+ (\d+)$/;
    }
    else {
         # FALLTHROUGH to ||= init on next line
    }

    $cols ||= 80; # non-unix or stty error
    $cols  -=  2;

    my $format  = "format STDOUT = \n"
                . '    ^'    . '<' x ($cols-4) . "\n"
                . '$_' . "\n"
                . "       ^" . "<" x ($cols-6) . "~~\n"
                . '$_' . "\n"
                . ".\n"
                . "1;" # for true eval return
                ;

    eval($format) || die;
}
```

The code for constructing the `format` dynamically based on the current screen width could be prettier, but it’s still useful.

Comment: Thanks for the instructive and interesting answer. It obviously counts as a counterexample to the premise of my question.